# How can I have multiple criteria when setting a filter

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following code to set a filter using Google Apps Script in a Google Sheet. What I really want as the filter is when the date is before today OR equal to today, OR if the cell is empty. How can I set up such OR logics?

```
  var newCriteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
     .whenDateBefore(SpreadsheetApp.RelativeDate.TODAY)
     .build();  
  dataSheet.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(3, newCriteria);
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand. What I am after is a filter like this: https://www.screencast.com/t/EqkIkgBkhk @Marios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use built in formula with [`.whenFormulaSatisfied()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter-criteria-builder#whenformulasatisfiedformula):

```
const formula = '=OR(C2<=TODAY(),C2="")';//only needs to refer to the first non header row. Rest will be applied automatically
const newCriteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
 .whenFormulaSatisfied(formula)
 .build();
```

Comment: I tried the same approach but I used arrayformulas instead because I thought that we had to pass all the values and it failed. Nice solution :)

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

Although the other solution is way more elegant, here is my approach that uses a different method:

```
function filterDates() {
  
  const dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  
  if(dataSheet.getFilter() != null) {
     dataSheet.getFilter().remove();
}
  
  const dates=dataSheet.getRange(2,3,dataSheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues().flat();
  const dates_str=dataSheet.getRange(2,3,dataSheet.getLastRow(),1).getDisplayValues().flat();
  const h_dates=[];
  
  dates.forEach((d,index)=>{
   if(d>new Date()){h_dates.push(dates_str[index]);}});
  
  const criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  .setHiddenValues(h_dates)
  .build();
  dataSheet.getDataRange().createFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(3, criteria);
  
}
```

---

### Method:

- I find the dates as strings that satisfy the desired conditions,
- then I filter out these values using: [.setHiddenValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter-criteria-builder#sethiddenvaluesvalues)